# What causes the change in the expected value of the product of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, utility

The following question is part of a homework exercise on portfolio theory that I have to do.

> Suppose that $Y$ is a random variable representing the returns on an investment. Now, let $f$ be a continuous, concave, strictly increasing  function of $Y$. Let $\xi^*$ be the amount invested in security Y that maximizes $E[f(\xi^*Y)]$. Show that $(\xi^*>0)$ iff $E[Y]>0$.

Comment: Maybe I am on the wrong track. Posting the problem that I'm trying to solve might help. Here it is:

Consider a market with only one risky asset $(d=1)$. Let $u: D \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Assume also that $\mathbb{E}[|u(\xi \cdot Y)|] < \infty$. Let the $\xi^*$ be the optimal investment for the risky asset. Then $\mathbb{E}[Y\cdot u'(\xi^* Y)] = 0$. 
Show, by inspecting the objective function $\xi \to \mathbb{E}[u(\xi\cdot Y)]$ near $\xi = 0$, that $\xi^* > 0$ iff $\mathbb{E}[Y] > 0$.

Comment: Thanks for updating, that is helpful. See edited answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $u$ can be seen as a utility function, hence the idea is to find where your expected marginal utility is 0, similar to normal economics with deterministic payoff functions and utilities. Since the function is integrable over the reals, you can take the derivative inside the integral of the LHS of your objective function to get the marginal expected utility function: $\frac{d}{d\xi}\int u(\xi y) f(y) dy = \int \frac{d}{d\xi}u(\xi y) f(y) dy = \int yu'(\xi y) f(y) dy = E[Yu'(\xi Y)] =$ expected marginal utility.

Setting it to zero gives you the condition you mentioned: $E[Yu'(\xi^* Y)] =0$

Now, using Jensen's inequality, we know $E[u(\xi Y)] \leq u(\xi E[Y])$ since the function is strictly increasing, convex function. Therefore, we can only hope to have a positive utility on our investment if $E[Y]>0$. There is an implicit assumption that I made here that $(x<0) \longrightarrow (u(x)<0)$, otherwise, you would benefit from a loss.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I still do not see why the "Therefore" in your last sentence is so obvious. The function is strictly increasing and concave, but not necessarily positive (in our definition). We can assume  that $\mathbb{E}[u(\xi Y)] \geq 0$ (otherwise the investment would not make sence), and thus, that $u(\xi \mathbb{E}[Y])$ must be at least zero. But that does not give any information about the argument of $u(\cdot)$.

Comment: You said in your post that f(Y) was a continuous, positive, strictly decreasing function of Y. If you mean strictly *increasing* and *concave* (i.e., risk-averse utility function), then the same result holds from Jensen's inequality, as we have reversed both the monotonicity and curvature senses. You said that the function is *not* necessarily positive, which is consistent with a strictly increasing concave function. However, you then assume that $E[Y]>0$ when, in your comment to your post, that assumption was what we were trying to prove.

Comment: (cont'd) - you are correct that for the investment to make sense, the expected utility should be positive. But if I read your clarification correctly, we are trying to show that you can only have positive expected utility when $E[Y]>0$. Jensen's inequality does this for us...it allows us to bound the expected value of a function by the value of the function as the expected value of its argument. Since you have an increasing, concave function, this theorem is useful in showing that the upper bound is negative with negative expected value for Y.

Comment: Final note - there is an assumption that you do not assign positive utility to losses, which makes sense. I.e, $u(X<0)<0$, otherwise, you actually get a benefit by losing money and E[Y]<0 may still be a good investment for you.

Comment: Oliver - u will be positive at some point and remain so afterwards by your definition. Are you saying that you can have negative utility for positve returns?

Comment: Yes, it could be possible that you have a negative utility for positive returns. But that only occurs if you study the functions purely mathematically. If you were to give an interpretation to the functions, it would not make sense to have negative utility for positive returns. BUt that can easily be solved by translating the function. Thanks for your explanation. I get it now.